# trying to upgrade to Spring4 no xml configuration webapp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-4

I'm trying to build a little hello world WebApp prototype with Spring 4 without any xml file configuration.

Than I use tomcat 7 and here is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Than I have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.spring4.configuration")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new 
                 InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

and the web initializer class:

```
public class HelloWorldInitializer extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/helloagain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World Again, from Spring 4 MVC");
    return "welcome";
}

}
```

and under WEB-INF the folder views that contains welcome.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>HelloWorld page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   Greeting : ${greeting}
 </body>
</html>
```

This is an example found [here](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) and doesn't work. I tried other similar examples but noone works.. can you explain me were I'm wrong?

---

Sorry the error is:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /Spring4FullAnnotation/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the 
target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

---

Damn.. I don't dowload the example I just copy the code in my eclipse... I don't have a maven project, I use maven just for resolving the dependencies (I create a Dynamic Web Project after that Configure -> Convert to maven project), than I normally run it on server. I have many project built as described above with Spring4 that are perfectly working.

I don't know why I can't launch this. The code is simple and the functioning can't depends of maven configuration..

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine for the following URL

http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorldNoXMLDemo-1.0.0/

Please check your URL